# How to count reactions different pages based on a month from a CSV with Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file, which I have read with Pandas.
I need to count how many different users liked each page in a given month for example in May.

Here is a sample about my CSV:

```
username,page,date
usera,sample1,2021-05-04
userb,sample1,2021-05-04
usera,sample1,2021-05-05

userd,sample2,2021-05-06
userc,sample2,2021-05-07
userc,sample2,2021-05-08
userc,sample2,2021-05-09
userf,sample2,2021-05-09
userx,sample2,2021-06-01

sample1 2 users liked in 05 month
sample2 3 users liked in 05 month
```

Here is my sample code I don't know how to filter to a specific date?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv")

print(df.groupby(['page']).size().reset_index(name='username'))
```

Does this code filter the different users and pages in the correct way?
Could you help me to filter the dates as well?

Answer (score 0):

Convert `date` column to datetime using `pd.to_datetime`, this way you can use the accessor object ([`dt.month`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.html)) for datetimelike values when grouping the dataframe. Use `drop_duplicates` to get only those unique user who liked each page in a given month. Then, use `apply(len)` to count how many different users liked each page. From here you can `reset_index` to place the indices as columns (this will facilitate the construction of the output string) and use `iterrows` to iterate over each row to print the message in the desired format.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv")

# convert to datetime to use 'dt.month' in the groupby
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df = df.drop_duplicates(['page', 'username'])
g = df.groupby(['page', df['date'].dt.month])

# count how many different users liked each page in a given month
page_count = g.apply(len)
page_date_cnt = page_count.reset_index(level=[0,1])

for idx, frame in page_date_cnt.iterrows():
    print(f"{frame['page']}: {frame[0]} users liked in {frame['date']:02} month")
```

Output:

```py
sample1: 2 users liked in 05 month
sample2: 3 users liked in 05 month
sample2: 1 users liked in 06 month
```